# Setting up Hero Card in V4

Tags: node.js, botframework, carousel, adaptive-cards

I need to implement a logic where On clicking of a carousel, it should prompt the user with an adaptive card with form details using Node JS in Microsoft Bot framework V4 version. Could You please help me on providing any sample code.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @yeya FYI, you can generate that link using `[ask]`: [ask].

Comment: Your title says hero card but your question body says Adaptive Card. Which is it?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the Microsoft samples?
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/07.using-adaptive-cards